# SSIS package to run script file on Azure

Tags: sql, azure, ssis, azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage

I want to create a SSIS package which will first get the .sql script file from Azure Blob storage and then execute the same in Azure sql server. I am able to do it when I am using local storage. That means when I am executing local file not from azure storage.

Please help me!!!

Comment: What error message do you receive when use azure storage? Could you give more details to help us to reproduce this issue?

Comment: I am not having any error but I have no idea how to create SSIS package for azure storage and azure sql server task. Can you please tell me how can i proceed?

Comment: I have a stub answer below, if you need more guidance on reading the file into SSIS to execute the SQL command, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Frist, you're going to want to set up your Azure storage with [Azure File Storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files/) That way the machine running your SSIS package will be able to use the file storage like a mapped network drive.

Once you've got that setup, the first step in your package will first run an Execute process Task.  This Task should be configured so that it runs a simple batch file (bat) that reconnects to the file share you setup in Azure File Storage.  Here is a basic example of what would be in this batch file:

```
if not exist e:\* 
  net use e: \\<storageAccountName>.file.core.windows.net\<fileContainerName> /u:<storageAccountName> <primary access key for storage account>
```

After this is run, your SSIS package would then be able to access your .sql files stored on this share.

Simply pick up the file, read the contents and execute the statement contained in the .sql file.